# Start of the line with regex in Ubuntu 22.04's gedit text editor

Tags: regular-expression, gedit

I try to use regex such as `^` to find the start of the line in the `gedit` editor in Ubuntu 22.04 but it doesn't work. Also for `$` as the end of the line.

Other regular expressions such as `\n`,`\d`,`\s` work well

Comment: What's the "standard text editor" you're talking about? `ed`, `ex` or `vi` (the 3 that I know are in the POSIX standard)? Or are you talking of `gedit` as the tag suggests?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and clarify which editor. If you are using a GUI one, it's probably `gedit`, but Ubuntu also uses `nano` as the default command line editor. As far as I know, `gedit` doesn't support regular expression search, it is just a very simple editor.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, it is gedit and it supports some of regular expressions.

Comment: Think of `gedit` like `notepad` in windows. Yes, a bit unfair because it is a little bit better. But It is still very basic (and slow for big files). Install a better text editor, this is one of the first things I do after installing my system. I prefer `geany`. In search field you can enable regex search and/or multiline match.

Comment: AFAICT `gedit` supports regexps in its *Find and replace* if you tick the regex box, but not in *Find* unless you install extra plugins.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It doesn't soppert `^` or `$` in the Find and Replace mode, but supports `\n`, `\d`, etc and I don't know how to type an analogue for `^`

Comment: It does for me with `gedit` 3.36.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 at least provided I tick the "Regular expression" box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` and `$` work in `gedit`'s *Find and replace* provided you tick the *Regular expression* box but `gedit`  skips empty matches.

`^$`, `^` alone match an empty string so won't be replaced. `x*` matches 0 or more `x`'s but `gedit` won't replace the occurrences matching 0 `x`'s, so it's equivalent to using `x+`.

If you want to use *Find and replace* to insert something at the start of the line, instead of replacing `^` with `something`, which won't work, you can replace `^.` (the first character of the line) with `something\0` (`something` followed by what was matched), bearing in mind that it won't work for empty lines where `^.` doesn't match.

You can however replace `(?s)^.` with `something\0`. By enabling the `s` flag, `.` will also match on newline, so it will also work on empty lines. The only case where I find it doesn't work is on the last line if it happens to be empty, presumably because `gedit` doesn't include the line delimiter of the last line in the buffer its regexp matches against.

And to replace empty lines with `something`, replace `^\n` with `something\n` instead of `^$` with `something`. Again, that  doesn't work for the last line.